# What's the default IAM permissions for a Lambda ARN?

Tags: aws-lambda

Assuming you create a Lambda ARN and Publish it, what are the default IAM permissions for that Lambda ARN?

i.e. can anyone go ahead and use it if they have the ARN?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a lambda, you have to assign an IAM role to it. There are no predefined roles, although there are some predefined policies that you can assign to a role. As a minimum you would want to allow it to write logs to CloudWatch. If you wanted the lambda to access an S3 bucket, that policy would need to be assigned to the role.

The role you assign to a Lambda only defines what that Lambda can do, not what can invoke it. You can assign triggers for other AWS services to invoke the Lambda, but you can't say set a policy in the lambda role or trigger that would allow anything to invoke it.

If you wanted to invoke the lambda directly (e.g. though an SDK), you would need an IAM role that had permission to invoke that lambda.

The ARN (Amazon Resource Name) is just a naming convention that AWS uses to find something.

Comment: But does that mean that someone with that ARN could find your Lambda function and view it?

Comment: ARN is just the reference used to identify it. Someone would need a role with permissions to do anything with it (invoke, amend, etc.). AWS has some fine grained controls, so you could give someone/something as much or as little access as you wanted.